# List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'FutureOr<List<>> in flutter

Tags: flutter

Here is my response from API

```
 {
  "success": true,
  "data": {
    "store 1": [
      {
        "id": 27,
        "cart_id": 5,
        "item": {
          "id": 35,
          "name": "test prod 1"
        }
      },
      {
        "id": 28,
        "cart_id": 56,
        "item": {
          "id": "jk",
          "name": "test prod 2"
        }
      },
      {
        "id": 27,
        "cart_id": 5,
        "item": {
          "id": 35,
          "name": "test prod 1"
        }
      }
    ],
    "store 2": [
      {
        "id": 27,
        "cart_id": 5,
        "item": {
          "id": 35,
          "name": "test prod 1"
        }
      },
      {
        "id": 28,
        "cart_id": 56,
        "item": {
          "id": "jk",
          "name": "test prod 2"
        }
      },
      {
        "id": 27,
        "cart_id": 5,
        "item": {
          "id": 35,
          "name": "test prod 1"
        }
      }
    ],
    "store 3": [
      {
        "id": 27,
        "cart_id": 5,
        "item": {
          "id": 35,
          "name": "test prod 1"
        }
      },
      {
        "id": 28,
        "cart_id": 56,
        "item": {
          "id": "jk",
          "name": "test prod 2"
        }
      },
      {
        "id": 27,
        "cart_id": 5,
        "item": {
          "id": 35,
          "name": "test prod 1"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

here is api function

```
Future<List<ShoppingCartModel>> getShoppingCart() async {
  
if (response.data['success'] == true) {
  var allStores = response.data['data'];
  var cartList = allStores.keys
      .map((name) => ShoppingCartModel(
            sname: name,
            storeList: allStores[name]
                .map<Store>((store) => Store(
                      id: store['id'],
                      cartid: store['cart_id'],
                      item: item(
                        id: store['item']['id'],
                        name: store['item']['name'],
                       
                      ),
                    ))
                .toList(),
          ))
      .toList();
  print(json.encode(cartList));
  // List listData = cartList;
  // cartList.map((f) => ShoppingCartModel.fromJson(f)).toList();
  return cartList;
```

here is my model

```
class Store {
  int id;
  int cartid;
  Item item;

  Store({this.id, this.cartid, this.item});

  Store.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    id = json['id'];
    cartid = json['cart_id'];
    item = Item.fromJson(json["item"]);
  }
  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['id'] = this.id;
    data['cart_id'] = this.cartid;
    data['item'] = item.toJson();

    return data;
  }
}

class Item {
  int id;
  String name;
 

  Item({
    this.id,
    this.name,
    
  });

  Item.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    id = json['id'];
    name = json['name'];
    //price = json['price'].toDouble();
  
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['id'] = this.id;
    data['name'] = this.name;
   

    return data;
  }
}
```

here is the api calling part

```
List<ShoppingCartModel> data = await _apiProvider.getShoppingCart();
```

I am getting error as 'List' is not a subtype of type 'FutureOr<List>'

where am i missing i have changed so many things but still issue is there. Initially i am geeting as object an then  i am coverting to array object and also i need to list this to list builder where first loop is for store and second loop i s for items

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can copy paste run full code below 
1 Your demo json string has typo `"id": "jk"` and `"id": 35` use different type 
2 Use `Map<String, dynamic> allStores` and `List<ShoppingCartModel> cartList` 
3 To prove it work, I have modified your json string and show with nested `ListView`, see working demo below

code snippet

```
Map<String, dynamic> allStores = response.data['data'];
List<ShoppingCartModel> cartList = allStores.keys
  .map((name) => ShoppingCartModel(
        sname: name,
        storeList: allStores[name]
            .map<Store>((store) => Store(
                  id: store['id'],
                  cartid: store['cart_id'],
                  item: Item(
                    id: store['item']['id'],
                    name: store['item']['name'],
                  ),
                ))
            .toList(),
      ))
  .toList();
```

working demo

[image]

full code

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:dio/dio.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class ShoppingCartModel {
  String sname;
  List<Store> storeList;

  ShoppingCartModel({this.sname, this.storeList});

  ShoppingCartModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    sname = json['sname'];
    storeList =
        List<Store>.from(json["storeList"].map((x) => Store.fromJson(x)));
  }
  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['sname'] = this.sname;

    data['storeList'] = List<dynamic>.from(storeList.map((x) => x.toJson()));

    return data;
  }
}

class Store {
  int id;
  int cartid;
  Item item;

  Store({this.id, this.cartid, this.item});

  Store.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    id = json['id'];
    cartid = json['cart_id'];
    item = Item.fromJson(json["item"]);
  }
  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['id'] = this.id;
    data['cart_id'] = this.cartid;
    data['item'] = item.toJson();

    return data;
  }
}

class Item {
  int id;
  String name;

  Item({
    this.id,
    this.name,
  });

  Item.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    id = json['id'];
    name = json['name'];
    //price = json['price'].toDouble();
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['id'] = this.id;
    data['name'] = this.name;

    return data;
  }
}

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  Future<List<ShoppingCartModel>> _future;

  @override
  void initState() {
    _future = getShoppingCart();
    super.initState();
  }

  Future<List<ShoppingCartModel>> getShoppingCart() async {
    String jsonString = '''
     {
  "success": true,
  "data": {
    "store 1": [
      {
        "id": 27,
        "cart_id": 1,
        "item": {
          "id": 35,
          "name": "test prod 1"
        }
      },
      {
        "id": 28,
        "cart_id": 2,
        "item": {
          "id": 36,
          "name": "test prod 2"
        }
      },
      {
        "id": 27,
        "cart_id": 3,
        "item": {
          "id": 35,
          "name": "test prod 1"
        }
      }
    ],
    "store 2": [
      {
        "id": 27,
        "cart_id": 4,
        "item": {
          "id": 35,
          "name": "test prod 4"
        }
      },
      {
        "id": 28,
        "cart_id": 5,
        "item": {
          "id": 37,
          "name": "test prod 5"
        }
      },
      {
        "id": 27,
        "cart_id": 6,
        "item": {
          "id": 35,
          "name": "test prod 6"
        }
      }
    ],
    "store 3": [
      {
        "id": 27,
        "cart_id": 7,
        "item": {
          "id": 35,
          "name": "test prod 7"
        }
      },
      {
        "id": 28,
        "cart_id": 8,
        "item": {
          "id": 38,
          "name": "test prod 8"
        }
      },
      {
        "id": 27,
        "cart_id": 9,
        "item": {
          "id": 35,
          "name": "test prod 9"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
    ''';

    Response response =
        Response(data: json.decode(jsonString), statusCode: 200);

    if (response.data['success'] == true) {
      Map<String, dynamic> allStores = response.data['data'];
      List<ShoppingCartModel> cartList = allStores.keys
          .map((name) => ShoppingCartModel(
                sname: name,
                storeList: allStores[name]
                    .map<Store>((store) => Store(
                          id: store['id'],
                          cartid: store['cart_id'],
                          item: Item(
                            id: store['item']['id'],
                            name: store['item']['name'],
                          ),
                        ))
                    .toList(),
              ))
          .toList();

      print(json.encode(cartList));
      // List listData = cartList;
      // cartList.map((f) => ShoppingCartModel.fromJson(f)).toList();
      return cartList;
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: FutureBuilder(
          future: _future,
          builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<List<ShoppingCartModel>> snapshot) {
            switch (snapshot.connectionState) {
              case ConnectionState.none:
                return Text('none');
              case ConnectionState.waiting:
                return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
              case ConnectionState.active:
                return Text('');
              case ConnectionState.done:
                if (snapshot.hasError) {
                  return Text(
                    '${snapshot.error}',
                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.red),
                  );
                } else {
                  return ListView.separated(
                      separatorBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                        return SizedBox(
                          height: 10,
                        );
                      },
                      shrinkWrap: true,
                      itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
                      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                        return Column(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                          children: <Widget>[
                            Row(
                                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                                children: <Widget>[
                                  Expanded(
                                      flex: 1,
                                      child: Text(snapshot.data[index].sname)),
                                  Expanded(
                                    flex: 2,
                                    child: Container(
                                      height: 50,
                                      child: ListView.separated(
                                          separatorBuilder:
                                              (BuildContext context,
                                                  int index) {
                                            return SizedBox(
                                              width: 10,
                                            );
                                          },
                                          shrinkWrap: true,
                                          scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                                          itemCount: snapshot
                                              .data[index].storeList.length,
                                          itemBuilder:
                                              (context, storeListIndex) {
                                            return Row(
                                                mainAxisAlignment:
                                                    MainAxisAlignment.center,
                                                crossAxisAlignment:
                                                    CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                                                children: <Widget>[
                                                  Container(
                                                    width: 120,
                                                    child: Column(
                                                      children: <Widget>[
                                                        Text(
                                                          snapshot
                                                              .data[index]
                                                              .storeList[
                                                                  storeListIndex]
                                                              .item
                                                              .name,
                                                          style: TextStyle(
                                                              color:
                                                                  Colors.red),
                                                        ),
                                                        Text(
                                                          snapshot
                                                              .data[index]
                                                              .storeList[
                                                                  storeListIndex]
                                                              .cartid
                                                              .toString(),
                                                          style: TextStyle(
                                                              color:
                                                                  Colors.red),
                                                        ),
                                                      ],
                                                    ),
                                                  )
                                                ]);
                                          }),
                                    ),
                                  )
                                ])
                          ],
                        );
                      });
                }
            }
          }),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () async {
          var a = await getShoppingCart();
        },
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please attach your getShoppingCart() function.

```
While i waiting, be aware of 
List<ShoppingCartModel> data = await _apiProvider.getShoppingCart();
'List' is not a subtype of type 'FutureOr<List>'
```

If you returning to a future from a function, better you have to set into a future.

```
Future<List<ShoppingCartModel>> data = await _apiProvider.getShoppingCart();
```

or, you can open the future instead

```
_apiProvider.getShoppingCart().then((response){
/// response will returning List<ShoppingCartModel>
/// depends on what you returning on the getShoppingCart methods
/// try to print the response length, because it's returning a list, or try grab an object instead from the first list
print(response.length);
});
```

Comment: added getShoppingCart() function